# Find variables in Bash function scope?

Tags: bash, function, shell, variables, scope

You can get info on environment variables in Bash with `set` and `env`. How can you get info only on the the variables used in a function?

```
myfunction(){ a=10; b=5; COMMAND; }
```

Is there a `COMMAND` that only returns vars in the function, without returning any other environment vars?

```
a=10
b=5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is. But you can fake it, from an empty bash-script write the result of `compgen -A variable` to file (since the environment is different in a interactive-shell compared to the one in a shell where you execute your script) and then in your bash-function/script do the same and diff those.

Using this approach on the script below, I get:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=5
b=10
c="test"
```

:

```
47a48
> PIPESTATUS
73a75,77
> a
> b
> c
```

See [chapter 8.7](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins) in bash manual